# Automatic positioning of images and tables in PowerPoint slide officer

Tags: r, flextable, officer

Hi so I have I am trying to write my own function that will automatically size and central align the images/tables that I am generating from officer.
The top/left functions in the add_image and add_table are good when I add each table manually as The differing tables are differing sizes but I wasn't sure how to automatically do it for different shaped images and tables.
I have the following code for images:

```
Image <- function(PP,title,footer,pageNO,path){
  im <- load.image(path)
  width <- imager::width(im)
  height <- imager::height(im)
  ratio <- width/height
  if(ratio < 9.15 / 3.6){
    y <- 3.6
    x <- 3.6 * ratio
  }
  if(ratio >= 9.15 / 3.6){
    y <- 9.15 / ratio
    x <- 9.15
  }
  PP <- PP %>% 
    add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "title", str = title) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "dt", str = format(Sys.Date())) %>%
    ph_with_img(type = "body", src = path, height = y, width = x) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "ftr",str = footer) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "sldNum", str = pageNO)
}
```

I would then like to align this image in the centre of the slide but am not sure how I would do this.

Then the same for tables but I have no idea how to do this as I would have to automatically rescale the width and height of columns based on original width and height of the flextable image as I wouldn't want to lose the aspect ratio unless there is a different way?
Current code for this is: but it doesn't do any resizing:

```
Slide <- function(PP,title,footer,pageNO,table){
  PP <- PP %>% 
    add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "title", str = title) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "ftr",str = footer) %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "dt", str = format(Sys.Date())) %>%
    ph_with_flextable(value = table, type = "body") %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "sldNum", str = pageNO)
}
```

Many thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The solution I've been using is to just specify the `left` (left offset argument) as `(slide_width - img_width)/2` manually, which centers the image horizontally (same idea for vertically)

Comment: That seems like a good option, I will try implementing that :), thanks for your response - How would you look at doing it for tables?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to work, changed thje line to this:
ph_with_img(type = "body", src = path, height = y, width = x,left = (slide_width - img_width)/2) and it gave me this error message:
Error in ph_with_img(., type = "body", src = path, height = y, width = x,  : 
  unused argument (left = (slide_width - img_width)/2)
where this was defined as left = (9.15 - x)/2)
@IceCreamToucan

Comment: See `?ph_with_img`. `ph_with_img_at` is the one with a `left` argument

Comment: Thanks - I've got it working now - just need to tinker around with the height as my slide isn't identical at top and bottom - thanks I appreciate your help

Comment: @IceCreamToucan do you know how to do this for tables as well as figures? Have only been able to get it working for images, struggled on the expanding on figures - not quite sure how to approach it

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if anyone's looking here's a reproducible example that does the following:

- Create a new PowerPoint deck;
- Create a `flextable` table that we'd like to include;
- Put the table in the centre of a new slide; and,
- Write it to file.

You can extend this to solve more particular problems, e.g. by using PowerPoint templates, using `officer::layout_properties()` to get more details about layouts, and so on.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(flextable)

# create a PowerPoint slide deck
deck <- officer::read_pptx()

# make a fletable with the first 5 rows of mtcars
deck_table <- mtcars %>%
  head(5) %>%
  flextable::flextable()

# get table dimensions
table_width <- sum(dim(deck_table)$widths)
table_height <- sum(dim(deck_table)$heights)

# get slide dimensions in inches
# these are from PowerPoint defaults for 3:4; widescreen width is 13.333 in
slide_width <- 10
slide_height <- 7.5

# find the left and top margins to centre the table
table_leftmargin <- (slide_width - table_width)/2
table_topmargin  <- (slide_height - table_height)/2

# add a slide, then add the table at the desired location
deck %>%
  officer::add_slide() %>%
  officer::ph_with(value = deck_table,
                   location = officer::ph_location(left = table_leftmargin,
                                                   top = table_topmargin))

# save to file
print(deck, "test.pptx")
```